# Extending the typewriter effect in python

Tags: python-3.x

How would you extend this code below to all strings between the start of a function and the end?

```
import time
import sys
from random import randrange

text ='Welcome to our agency.'

for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        seconds = "0." + str(randrange(1, 4, 1))
        seconds = float(seconds)
        time.sleep(seconds)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you want to accomplish.

Comment: The code above adds a typewriter effect to a string - as though someone is typing it in (chatbot).  How would you extend this to six or seven strings?  Would you need to add it each time, or could you write a function that does this when imported?

Comment: [`random()*0.2 + 0.1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random)

Comment: Or, for that matter, `randrange(1, 4)/10`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to package the repeatable code into a function:

```
def typewriter_effect(text):
    for c in text:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        seconds = "0." + str(randrange(1, 4, 1))
        seconds = float(seconds)
        time.sleep(seconds)
```

After this you can call the function with different text. The argument string is available as `text` within the function.

```
typewriter_effect('Welcome to our agency.')
typewriter_effect("What's your inquiry?')
```

You can find numerous [tutorials](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) about user-defined functions in python.

Comment: How would I use that with this?  first_name = input(' What is your name? ').capitalize()

Comment: This starts to sound like a homework assignment... To answer the question, you can first print the text: `typewriter_effect(' Whats your name?')` and then prompt with an empty input `first_name =  input().capitalize()`.